# Naming a New C API

Tags: c, api, naming

This might not be the ideal place to ask this question, but I'm really at a dead end and don't know where else to ask (suggestions would be appreciated).

I'm trying to come up with a name for 4 new API's for my company's C Library.

These API's are being added to an existing set, so they have to match an already made pattern, which limits my choices.

What all of the API's (existing and new) do is allow the user to get/set the value string or nonstring variables used in a program.

The way mine are different is that they allow you to get the value using the name of the variable, as apposed to already existing methods.

Here is what I currently have:

```
VariableGetValueString
VariableSetValueString
VariableGetValue
VariableSetValue
```

The only problem with this, is that it does not make it clear that it uses the NAME of the variable.  I cannot think of a non-cluttered sounding name that makes this clear to the customer.

Preferably, there should be nothing removed from the names, as it matches the patterns of the other API's (which do not explicitly state their retrieval methods in their names, though this one should, for extraneous reasons).

Any help is appreciated, and though I know there is no definitive answer, I will obviously accept the one that fits the best.

Sorry again if this is a poor place to ask the question, I would love suggestions of a more appropriate place if there is one.

EDIT:

Some existing API names are:

```
VariableGetTaskString
VariableGetTask
VariableGetGlobalString
VariableGetGlobal
```

Along those lines.  `Task` and `Global` refer to the scope of the variable.  They weren't named very well in the first place, which makes my job more difficult, but they cannot be changed because customers have grown used to them and the changes would break old programs.  I didn't include these initially because of how little help they offer (in my opinion).

The parameters of each API will make it obvious to the customer what each one does, but it would be preferable for the name to do that as well.  Thanks for your feedback.

EDIT 2:

Here is an example of a call into the API:

```
if(!VariableGetValueString(Handle handle, LPCSTR variableName, TaskID taskID, LPSRT value, DWORD bufferSizeinBytes)
{
    //retrieve failed.
}

if(!VariableGetValue(Handle handle, LPCSTR variableName, TaskID taskID, PDWORD value)
{
    //retrieve failed.
}
```

Hope thats clear enough.  Feel free to keep asking for more, I'll edit this all day.  Thanks for the continued support.

Comment: use the word of or by a lot

Comment: @Quonux haha, that is exactly what I intended to avoid...

Comment: What do the typical function signatures look like? Can you provide examples? Do your new functions differ enough in their signature for the hint to come from that difference? Can you name the parameters to provide the hint?

Comment: @JamesMorris The names of the parameters definitely give a huge hint, the value is a string. So I could rely on just that, but more would be better. Editing post to reflect those requests now

Comment: It's an opinion based question so I will provide an opinion as an answer: It is possible to create a new naming convention while marking old names as supported but deprecated.  Having said that, your names are sufficiently simple; Can you show an example of how the user may be using say `VariableGetValue` ?  It would help to suggest something reasonable.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I like that idea, but I don't know if it would be viable in my case... I'll look into it though.  Ill make that edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

### suggestion 1

```
UseVariableNameToGetTaskString(...);
UseVariableNameToGetTask(...);
UseVariableNameGetGlobalString(...);
UseVariableNameToGetGlobal(...);
```

### suggestion 2

```
VariableGetTaskStringByVarName(...);
VariableGetTaskByVarName(...);
VariableGetGlobalStringByVarName(...);
VariableGetGlobalByVarName(...);
```

### suggestion 3

```
VariableGetTaskStringByName(...);
VariableGetTaskByName(...);
VariableGetGlobalStringByName(...);
VariableGetGlobalByName(...);
```

Comment: I like the last, but they all just seem too wordy, maybe I'm being too picky

Comment: Again — very subjective, Windows identifiers are long anyhow, users won't have too much of an issue with typing the thing, especially if clarity is the primary objective. As a professional my humble advice is to not spend too much cycles on this problem, because it's an exercise in diminishing returns. If you like #3 use it :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
NamedVariableGetValueString
NamedVariableSetValueString
NamedVariableGetValue
NamedVariableSetValue
```

so that the distinction `NamedVariable` means a variable specified by name, whereas just `Variable` means a variable specified by ID or whatever the old functions use.

Comment: The named would have to not go at the beginning.  I have considered that, and some variations of it, I'm not crazy about it, but its the best I have...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`getVariableName()`

and

`setVariableName(char* value)`

Comment: The parameters aren't really in discussion here, they have already been decided on and are working and clear.  The only thing I wish to change is the actual names to clarify the purpose, and just rearranging the words doesn't do that.  Thank you though, I hope this comment doesn't seem snarky